# How to find sum of $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{3}{4} + \frac{5}{6}+...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Today, I was practicing some question then this question came in my mind.

How can we find the sum of first n terms of the series which is of the form,
$\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{3}{4} + \dfrac{5}{6}+...\sf upto\, nth\, term$

Just like we have formulas,

> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$
> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Any hint would be helpful to me.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have any formula that you might expect. Does $n-H_n/2$ do? Here $H_n$ refers to the **harmonic series**, which you can google about.

Comment: It looks like the $n$-th term is $(2n-1)/2n$, or $1-1/(2n)$. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Thanks, this formula worked. Can you tell what is it's origin or proof ?

Comment: ProThala - There's nothing special going on here. I just looked at the terms of the sequence and noticed a pattern, the same one used by @cansomeonehelpmeout in the answer below, which is a good one by the way. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may write the series as $$\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\ldots+\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=n-\frac{1}{2}H_n$$

I'm not aware of any nice form that doesn't use integrals.

Comment: For large n. Maybe he could try something like $\ln(n)+\gamma$ to approximate $H_{n}$. Or digamma function.